# Docker error: Parcel (Parceljs) won't work in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, containers, parceljs

When I run my nodejs application in a docker container, the parcel build step fails with an error message that isn't helpful. The app runs fine locally without Docker.

I created a simple app to test my problem out.
My package.json is

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.0.0-beta.2"
  }
}
```

and my Dockerfile is

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update &&\
    apk upgrade &&\
    apk add nodejs npm

# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 1234

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

The error message I get is `[Error: Invalid argument]`

More detailed steps:

1. The commands I run to build docker is `docker build .`
2. Then I run the app with `docker run test_app`

The build step works fine and creates the image.
When I run the container, this is the entire output

```
docker run test_app

> test@1.0.0 start
> parcel index.html

[Error: Invalid argument]
```

I have tried the following:

1. Using node:13, node:14, node:16 and my latest attempt was with alpine as the Docker image
2. I tried overriding as many of parcel js default options as I could to see if I could override the problem.

Again the issue only happens inside a docker container so I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong with my Docker setup. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What command are you running that produces that error (`docker build`, some flavor of `docker run`, `docker-compose up`)?  Is there a more detailed exception, with a stack trace, or any more of an error message than that?

Comment: @DavidMaze updated the question to include the steps to reproduce and the entire output. I'm afraid there's not much more to go on. (I also tried parcel's verbose log mode but that didn't change anything)

Comment: Would it have anything to do with this being a beta release? Does it work with parcel `1.12.4`?

Comment: @jabbson Just tried it out, and I got the same error :(

Comment: One more thing to check: do you have a `.dockerignore` file that contains `node_modules`?  (If you don't, the `COPY . .` line will overwrite the previous `RUN npm install` line with the `node_modules` directory from the host, which could result in odd behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running parcel from `/` ?
Try making a `WORKDIR` and then run parcel, works for me.